# how to validate business rules in node application with sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an express/node js application using sequelize orm. I want to know what would be a best place in the application to write validation for business rules. say i have a user model class as below. I have added some model validation to the class (in bold below) , for example Name cannot be empty. other than the model validation, where can i add some business rule validation , like if age is less than 18 or 16, you cannot have employerName or hoursWorkedPerWeek ( this is just for this example). example is contrived for this question.

is there a way to add such rules to the model class, if now how do i add that to the contorller class below.

user model class

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: 'id'
    },
    Name: { 
        type: DataTypes.STRING,  
        allowNull: false,
        **validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }**
     },
    age: {
    }, 
    hoursWorkedPerWeek: {
    }, 
    employerName: {
    }, 
    createdAt: {
     
    },
    updatedAt: {
    
    }
  }
  ....
);
```

controller class

```
static async add(user) {
      try {
             models.User.create(user).then(newUser => {
                 //do something
        }).catch(error => {
          throw error;
        }); 
    
      } catch (error) { 
          throw error;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the documentation it looks like you can pass in validation rules within the model definition: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#per-attribute-validations. Note the custom validators you can do at the end.

If you have a lot of validation going on, it might be beneficial to put it in one file and reference as necessary throughout your project.

Edit: Update to show example. Just as a heads up, I haven't implemented this but from the documentation this seems to follow.

```js
// validations.js

exports.ageValidator = value => {
    if(value < 18) {
        throw new Error("Invalid age.");
    }
}

// list other validators as needed here in the same manner
```

You can then import this into the class where your model is and add within the validate block.

```js
// within your User model
const validateModule = require(/* path to validations.js */);
const ageValidator = validateModule.ageValidator;

/*
    Add ageValidator to the `validate` section

    age:{
        validate: {
            customValidate(value) {
                ageValidator(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks , can you share some examples , of creating a separate file for custom validations. if you know of one.

Comment: thanks again. when you say documentation , you mean sequelize documentation or express?

Comment: Documentation of sequelize; the link I pasted in the answer.